# Why does it only show the first input?

Tags: javascript

```js
function showInput() {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  document.getElementById("user_input1").value;
  document.getElementById("user_input12").value;
  document.getElementById("user_input123").value;
  document.getElementById("user_input1234").value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input1">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input12">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input123">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input1234">
</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
<label>Your input: </label>
<p><textarea id='display'></textarea></p>
```

I wanted this code to show all the inputs but it only shows the first one. What can i do to fix that.

Comment: because the line ends at the semicolon.... So you have a bunch of statements that do nothing. You would need to use string concatenation to join them together. And submit buttons submit forms.

Comment: this is not the full code

Comment: okay.... and my comment still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `+` instead of `;`

```
function showInput() {
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
         document.getElementById("user_input").value +
         document.getElementById("user_input1").value +
         document.getElementById("user_input12").value +
         document.getElementById("user_input123").value + 
         document.getElementById("user_input1234").value; 
}
```

Comment: How do i add an <br> or \n to make it more organized?

Comment: @AvicT Use `"<br/>" +` after each `.value + `

Comment: @AvicT Well than you need to update the question and show me the problem.